# iPhone App crashes with NSCFType setImage:forState

Tags: iphone, crash

I have an app where i capture image from camera and set it to button.

So, after capturing image from camera and tap on use button, my app crashes with [NSCFType setImage:forstate] unrecognised instance

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *resizeImage = [image imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];    

   //convert the selected image to NSData
   toShowFullImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizeImage, 0.8);

    //retain it for further use 
    [toShowFullImage retain];

    //set the selected image to button

    UIImage *newimage=[image imageScaleAndCropToMaxSize:CGSizeMake(75, 75)];

    [button setImage:newimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This crash occurs in iOS 6.0.1 with Abort trap 6 error

Comment: please post code where you set image..

Comment: @ParasJoshi : I posted the code check my edit.

Comment: @user1530787: how did you add the button to your view ? please post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issues is when you set the background image of button it's already released.

**Possible ways of this issue:**

1. When you added the button to the view, you called `[button release];`
2. You created the button using factory methods like `buttonWithType:`

**Possible solutions:**

1. Don't call release after setting it to view.
2. Just retain the button if you created it using `buttonWithType:`
3. Set the image using tag.

When you add the button set a tag like:

```
button.tag = 7;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And set the image like:

```
 [[self.view viewWithTag:7] setImage:newimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I added the button in following manner :`       UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame=CGRectMake(65.0, 10.0, 75.0,75.0);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(getFullImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
` and i am not releasing button anywhere. Is this causing crash?? Please help me i am new to iOS development.

Comment: use the above code. add tag to the button. When you set the image refer the button using that tag.

Comment: I retain a button created using buttionWithType:, i have a doubt when and where to release this button.

Comment: If you declared the button as global then release it in dealloc, if it's local then use tag instead of retaining it.

Comment: Thanks it working but other issue occured i.e if i move my app to background and does not perform any action for some period of time and then open my app from background and take a pic from camera its crashing.

Comment: I think this is due to the code written in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`. You releasing or doing something in these methods, that makes it crash

Answer (score 0):

just check that you alloc the button or not and also give the reference with outlet or not also before set that image anywhere you relese this button then this type of error occured so check this flow mate.. and also see this code may this also easy to use for you..

instead of newimage.. direct set image to background of button for example..

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```